# GCD - Asynchronous Queue with Synchronous Tasks

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to download data from an API before displaying it to the user.

Here's what I am doing:

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

    __block NSMutableArray *newImages;

    dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
        newImages = [NSMutableArray array];
        // images retrieved using `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest`
    });

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // display images to the user
    });
});
```

My question is, since `newImages` is declared with `__block`, am I always guaranteed to have the latest `newImages` data when executing the second task at the main queue? If not, what's the safest way to pass that array's content into the second block and making sure its the latest content?

I think my data is getting messed up somewhere, hence why I am asking this.

If this looks fine, then I will post my full code for help with the whole thing in case something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sketch of a solution:

```
q = /* custom serial queue */
urls = /* urls array */;
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSURL *url in URLs) {
   NSURLRequest *req = [self imageRequestForURL:url];
   dispatch_async(q, ^{
     UIImage *image = [self imageFromRequest:req];
     [images addObject:newImage];
   }
}
dispatch_async(q, ^{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self applyUpdatesForURLs:urls withImages:images];
   });
}
```

The queue is a standard work queue.

The `applyUpdatesForURLs:withImages:` block is guaranteed to run after all images have been downloaded, by virtue of being enqueued in a serial queue after the image download blocks.

There's no synchronization problems with `images` because all code working with it runs serially not concurrently.

And the UI update ultimately occurs on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted method looks overly complex.  Why not use the NSURLConnection method, sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:. You can specify the mainQueue as the queue parameter to update your UI.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your server address"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *theData, NSError *error){
        if (error == nil) {
            //do what you want with theData and update the UI
        }
    }];
```

Comment: The problem is that I have multiple images that I want to download them all at once, and then perform the UI update on that. I am grabbing the images in a for-loop. The code you provided would do that image by image. Wouldn't updating the whole batch be better? I am actually updating the UI via `performBatchUpdates:completion` for `UICollectionView` as you've seen in my previous questions. What would you suggest? Should I replace `performBatchUpdates` with something else? If so, what would I use to perform one update after the other for the collection view?

Comment: It's hard for me to tell without knowing the details of your download, but there's no reason that the code I posted can't be used for a batch download. Does the download from the server contain an array of images (or some object that can be converted to an array)? If so, then you can still use performBatchUpdates:completion: to do the UI update.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple blocks in a concurrent queue updating a mutable array - it just won't work properly since mutable containers are not thread safe. When the image is available queue a block on the main queue, and add it to the array there instead.

Comment: Both blocks are dispatched synchronously though. Is that still not safe? If not, how would I queue a block on the main queue when an image is available? Could you please elaborate on that / give an example? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: When you use dispatch_sync, it just means you wait until it finished. If you have a concurrent queue that runs the block, then two blocks can be both trying to write the array. When you touch the array, it must be on a serial queue like the mainQueue (but it can be on any serial queue, if all accesses are on that queue - Mike Ash has may articles on this usage).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I ran an asynchronous queue in relation to the main thread. However, in that concurrent queue, I ran two synchronous blocks which should guarantee that they will run synchronously in that queue. Putting breakpoints, I am getting this behaviour as I expected. The first block finishes execution and the second one is executed to update the UI. But I believe that there "may" be some corrupt data. But querying the array it looks alright.

Comment: I don't have your code for this '// images retrieved using `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` - if those are concurrent then you can have multiple threads trying to modify the array.
'

Comment: I figured my issue is with UICollectionView and not GCD.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't `dispatch_sync()` on a concurrent queue. (Well, you can, but it's exactly the same as a `dispatch_async()`.) `dispatch_sync()` only makes any kind of conceptual sense on a serial queue, where you are saying, "I want to wait until all blocks queued up before me end, then do this block, then return control to the calling thread."

Second, [rdelmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12681233/72508) is correct - you are overcomplicating this. Even if you don't want to use the batch completion handler on `NSURLConnection`, you certainly don't need to nest two block dispatches on the concurrent queue - just one block which does the batch downloads (running async on a concurrent queue) with a nested block which does the UI update on the main queue upon completion is just fine!